# Localization Error while requesting DXA page using registered Domain URL configured in Docker

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, topology-manager, docker

Recently we have deployed a DXA site with a dev domain. After deployment when we have requested to the site suing dev domain an error logged saying no localization found error.

Please find the error message below:

> 12:07:14.589 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR
> c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Failed to retrieve localization
> for request url = https://dev-xxxxx.net/, uri = /
> com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationNotFoundException:
> Localization not found for https://dev-xxxxx.net/

While investing we found the app is hosted using kubernete cluster with port 8080.

In the topology we have registered the below two URLs:

1. https://dev-xxxxx.net [For dev domain]
2. http://localhost:8072 [For local setup and testing]

While the DXA app works for the URL http://localhost:8072 and gives localization error for the URL https://dev-xxxxx.net.

As port 8080 is registered for some other publication in the Topology, we have used port 8071 for our app.

Do we need to configure the Kubernete cluster with port 8072 in such case to access the app using https://dev-xxxxx.net or is there any other settings for such cases in DXA.

Please help !!

Comment: if you have two base url's  added to the topology for DXA app with 8071 and 8072 i assume your DXA will work for both. when you say other application using 8080. do you have multiple DXA app which runs on different ports. when it comes to kubernete you can have the web app service pointing to Port : 80 and targetPort 8072

Comment: you can expose mulitple target ports on kubernetes for the same webapp service

Answer (score 1):

Incase of docker it does not matter in which port the DXA application has been hosted. The docker sends the same url to the content API which it receives as request.

To confirm this, anyone can check the Content Microservice logs.

**With regards to the issue:**
The DXA application inside the docker was not able to update the `BinaryData` folder as it was set as Read Only. Once the docker configuration was changed to make the `BinaryData` folder writable by the DXA app, the application started working.

The confusion was due to the error logged in the DXA application saying

```
Localization not found for https://dev-xxxxx.net/
```